# What is the API to close another application by the app's handle?

Tags: c#, windows, api, delphi

I use ShellExecuteEx to open a MS Word document and get its handle. How can I use the handle to close the document? Thanks?

Comment: "*How can I use the handle to close the document?*" - you can't. The handle you get back is a process handle, not a window handle. And it is not even gauranteed to be a unique process, ie if the document is opened as a new tab in an existing multi-tab process.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can save the windows handle to a global variable, and then use the 'TerminateProcess' to terminate whatever you have executed.

Try this code for example:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, ShellApi;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
      SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  ExecuteFile: string;
  //ParamString, StartInString: string;
begin
  ExecuteFile:='C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe';
  FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0);
  SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  with SEInfo do
  begin
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    Wnd := Application.Handle;
    lpFile := PChar(ExecuteFile);
    //lpParameters := PChar(ParamString);
      {ParamString can contain the application parameters.}
    //lpDirectory := PChar(StartInString);
      {StartInString specifies the name of the working directory.
      If ommited, the current directory is used.}
    nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  end;
  if ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Notepad started.');
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Error starting Notepad!');

end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TerminateProcess(SEInfo.hProcess,0);
end;

end.
```

1. You have to put 'ShellApi' to uses units.
2. You have to declare as a global variable the 'SEInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;' where you will save the Window Handle, of the executed process.
3. Button1 will start the notepad.exe process.
4. Button2 will terminate the notepad.exe process you have opened with button1 (not the other notepad.exe processes you may have open to this computer)

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using of `TerminateProcess`. Why? `TerminateProcess` forcefully terminates the process whose handle you passed to it. This means that such process has no chance to perform any needed cleanup. In case of MS Word this would mean that user will not be prompted to save unsaved changes to the document which would mean that user loses all changes made since the last save. Or even worse if you call `TerminateProcess` while MS Word is saving last changes to the document file the saving process may be interrupted and you end up with damaged document file.

Comment: Hi, Thanks to George Betsis, SilverWarior. TerminateProcess works. I agree SilverWarior's opinion, SilverWarior, do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: ´TerminateProcess´won't work as you expect: it will close ALL documents because there is a single WinWord.exe for multiple documents.

Comment: TerminateProcess will terminate only the winword.exe process that handles the document you want. Not ALL the winword.exe processes. I have run the code locally on my pc, and it works just like that. Although, I agree with SilverWarior, that it will forcefully terminate the Word instance with the document, without even saving. You could instead, send WM_CLOSE message to the process (using SEInfo.hProcess handle) to prompt the user to save the document. You can send a WM_CLOSE (or a WM_QUIT) message using PostThreadMessage.

Comment: I use GetForegroundWindow to get the window handle, then GetWindowText retrieves the title, use the title to make a word title template, use the template and file name for findwindow to get the document's window handle, then SetWindowPos, post WM_CLOSE message. Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to running MSWORD COM object and use the API to find the document you want to close and close it using the same API.
Here an simple example showing how to close the active document:

```
unit VclWordComObjectDemoMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.Win.ComObj, Word_TLB;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    MsWord: _Application;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    SaveChanges    : OleVariant;
    OriginalFormat : OleVariant;
    RouteDocument  : OleVariant;
begin
    try
        MsWord := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application') as _Application;
    except
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Word is not already open or no document is open.');
        Exit;
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Connected to Word.');
    SaveChanges    := wdDoNotSaveChanges;
    OriginalFormat := EmptyParam;
    RouteDocument  := EmptyParam;
    MsWord.ActiveDocument.Close(SaveChanges,
                                OriginalFormat,
                                RouteDocument);
end;

end.
```

Word_TLB is obtained by importing Microsoft Word type library (Delphi / Menu / Component / Import component / Import a type library. Then select Microsoft Word in the list of type libraries. Then select Create a unit and add it to your project.

Comment: Can you add the code to actually choose one of many documents? Do they actually have "handles" (as OP wants) or would one need to analyze a list/array of documents again and again to find it?

Comment: Hi fpiette, I like your way. At the beginning, I used the Ole way to open and close words, but there is a problem, the words open on task bar as icon only, not open on top of windows, so users have to click on the word icon to view the documents. I tried to import the  Microsoft Word from the type library, I found it is version 14. I don't like the version specific implementation, because MS Word keep updating, our clients have all different versions of word, the latest version 16 causes our app problem. So I decide to choose a version independent way. Thank you very much, fpiette.

Comment: @AmigoJack The handle to OP talk about is the one of Word executable. He don't need a document handle (There isn't anyway).

Comment: @peter When you launch Word using OLE, you can change the ´visible´property to make Word visible on screen. If you have questions about using Word automation, please don't add it in comment here but create a new specific question.

Comment: @peter You can use the TLB for the oldest Word version you want to support. They are upward compatible starting from Word 97. Of course using an old type library you won't be able to use most recent Word features. If you have questions about using Word automation, please don't add it in comment here but create a new specific question.